# Is parsing JSON on the serverside dangerous?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a Python application with Django and serializing objects to and from JSON using Python's standard `json` library.

I've heard something along the lines that

> any seralizer/deserializer/parser is a potential security threat to the application

Is this really true on the serverside? Do I need to fear someone sending tampered JSON up to my instance and them having remote code execution privileges? I would think that there wouldn't be any security threats other than (potentially) XSS or SQL injection, which in my case (converting values to ints, storing all data in MongoDB) shouldn't be the case.

Should I be paranoid along these lines of parsing JSON data from clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON data can only contain basic types: strings, numbers, Booleans, null, objects, and lists.  This means that properly formatted JSON data poses no risk at all to your application, unless you are doing something silly like executing that code with `eval()`.

So if valid JSON is not an issue, the question becomes "can a client send any invalid data that poses a security risk when processed by Python's json module".  The answer here is also no, Python's json module will reliably raise a ValueError for invalid json data, with no scary side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In general that blurb is true, but is dependent on how security-enabled/conscious the parser and its developers are. The `json` module itself has been vetted for a long time, and does not do anything that would compromise the security of the server.

Answer (score 0):

> any seralizer/deserializer/parser is a potential security threat to the application

It is true on the serverside as long as you write seralizer/deserializer/parser by yourself.

As long as you use standard library you can trust its programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You never know what the parser does inside. A parsing itself is a possible security threat, although the developers try to do their best to avoid it.

For a stable library that's been developed for a long time, there's *nearly* no danger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should be paranoid. Just because the parsers are trusted does't mean you can't screw up.

Answer (score 0):

Well... to take any user input is potentially dangerous, especially when using external libraries you don't know well. For instance, it's simple to demonstrate how a quicksort algorithm poorly implemented can be used to a Denial of Service attack by feeding it tailored data that leads all iterations to an O(n²). Does that means sort algorithms are dangerous? No. It means poor implementations of anything can be dangerous.

Obviously, you should estimate the danger and benefits and choose what to adopt based on that. Frankly, if you were working on the kind of project where the potential risk of using a 3rd party json implementation is a security issue, you wouldn't be asking about it on Stack Overflow.